# Mongoose Aggregate: Empty results never trigger the callback

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I am working with mongoose and defined some aggregations in the mongoshell.
Sometimes the match criteria filters out all data. Nevertheless: Mongoose does not call a callback.

This was very easy reproducable,e.g.

```
Contract.aggregate( {
$match:{user:'dummydata'}}, 
function (err, result) {
  console.log('this never happens');
});
```

If I put in a existing user id, the callback gets called.
If I use a non existend user id, the callback just is never called.
But how should I know what happend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just by accident I found out, that there is the need for a second "no results" callback.

**So the right solution is**:

```
Contract.aggregate( {
    $match:{user:'dummydata'}
}, 
function (err, result) {
      console.log('this never happens');
}, 
function(err,result) {
 console.log('Crap there is no result');
});
```